# How can you calibrate extrusion multiplier value in Slic3r WITHOUT changing printer settings in memory?

Tags: prusa-i3, calibration, extrusion

Most tutorials ask you to change the printer settings using the `The command M92 E420 will set the new value which can be saved to memory (so that it is available after a printer power off/on cycle) using M500.`

But I just want to modify the Extrusion Multiplier in Slic3r's settings. It's default at for each filament, and I'd like to modify this by adding a profile for each roll I have after calibration.

[image]

What's the best way to do this? If I measure extruding 100mm and checking how much is left, what is the formula used to get the new EM value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide the amount overextruded by the desired amount. If you wanted 100mm but got 101mm, that's 1mm extra, or 1% over. Use an extrusion multiplier of 0.99 (1% under) to compensate - AND THEN DO ANOTHER TEST to confirm.

This modifier will be used by Slic3r to generate E values in your gcode without flashing anything.

I recommend saving this recipe with an intuitive name, like *Acme Green PLA.*